# how to print unicode character when using handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to print a Unicode character in an Ember 1.12.0 application but instead of getting the graphic that the code represents I'm simply getting the code printed to screen. In the example below, instead of getting the pencil, I simply get the code `\u270E` printed. This is what I'm doing in my `myemberapplication.hbs` file

```
<span {{action "someEmberAction" }}> \u270E</span>
```

Question: how do I print a Unicode character when using an `.hbs` file for a layout?

**Update.** This is not the same question as the one linked to
 The question  linked to is how to return a Unicode character from a computed property. My question is, how to get a Unicode character printed. Is a computed property the only way to do it? if so, then it's approaching the same topic from a different angle, but if there's more than one way to print a Unicode character then it's a question with a larger scope. Furthermore, that question was asked in 2013, and handlebars and Ember have changed quite a bit since then

Comment: it's not the same question. The question you linked to is how to return a Unicode character from a computed property. My question is, how to get a Unicode character printed. Is a computed property the only way to do it? if so, then it's approaching the same topic from a different angle, but if there's more than one way to print a Unicode character then it's a question with a larger scope.  Furthermore, that question was asked in 2013, and handlebars and Ember have changed quite a bit since then

Comment: It is old but the [solution](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qatuhizuce/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) is still the same. `{{{yourUnicode}}}` is all you need to print it out unescaped.

Comment: this `{{{ \u270E }}}` won't compile, says "INVALID" expecting `STRING, NUMBER, ID, DATA`, if I do `{{{ u270E }}}` (i.e. remove the slash) it prints nothing. If I do `{{{ "\u270E" }}}` it prints nothing.

Comment: Also, doing this prints nothing `{{{ '&#35;'}}}`

Comment: Why would you do that? If that's all it will contain just write it there in the first place

Comment: @kitler I'm not sure what your `Why would you do that?` refers to but if it's to my last comment, I only tried that because as I said in my second previous comment, I'm not able to get the Unicode character printed by trying any of the techniques in the second previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82306/discussion-between-kitler-and-brainlikeadullpencil).

Comment: @Kilter sorry I was away and didn't see your invite to chat.